# wordpressでのヘッダーメニュー デザインで境界線を波線にする方法

Tags: wordpress

いつもお世話になっております。

現在wordpressでLightiningの子テーマにて
webページを作成しており、
ヘッダーメニューのデザインの変更についてご質問させてください。

以下の写真はヘッダーメニューの部分ですが
下の部分のボーダー線をなみなみ線に変更したいと考えているのですが
いろいろ調べてみてもいまいちわかりませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なにかいい方法はございますでしょうか？

Comment: WordPressでは無いのですが、この記事が参考になるかも。[\[CSS\]コンテンツの区切り hr要素を素敵にデザインするスタイルシートのテクニックのまとめ](https://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/css/css-snippets-for-horizontal-rules.html)

Comment: リンクをご紹介頂き、ありがとうございます。